# Chrome won't open unlinked URLs on Android 11

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, url, hyperlinks

I have a Google Pixel 4a running Android 11, and I haven't been able to open any links in Chrome by tapping them. On my old Android 9 phone, I was able to tap/select a URL, and there was an option to open the URL in Chrome. I used this feature heavily when opening links from my email client.

Chrome is set as my default browser. In the app permissions for Opening Links, Chrome's option to open supported links is greyed out. The option to open supported links is also greyed out for all other web browsers.

[image]

Interestingly, if I select the first part of a link, like `https://www.example.com`, there is an option to open the URL in Chrome. But if I select the full link, like `https://www.example.com/abc`, then the option to open in Chrome disappears.

Screenshot for selecting partial link:

[image]

Screenshot for selecting full link:

[image]

My phone is rooted.

Comment: Did you update Chrome to the latest? I am able to open your *example.com/abc* also *https://onemileatatime.com/united-airlines-mileageplus/*

Comment: Also *https://onemileatatime.com/deals/world-of-hyatt-award-discount/* //Try clearing default and see (open by default)

Comment: Clearing cache of Chrome may help too

Comment: @beeshyams I cleared the default applications, cleared the Chrome cache, and updated Chrome. It is still the same result - when I select a URL, the option to open in Chrome does not appear.

Comment: I have also tried updating WebView and rebooting. Same result.

Comment: Very strange. Let's hope you get a solution soon

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings, apps, Chrome, there's a menu "browser app", where you may change the default browser from webview to Chrome.

This is probably related to the recent change to Webview. Google has decided that opening links with a generic chromium browser without any stored user information is more convenient for the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I have ended up doing is just tapping "Web search" when I select a URL. I set the default browser to Chrome as you mentioned, and tapping "Web search" opens the URL in Chrome.